# Defining paths to .jar file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jar

I would like to ask how to define path to files stored directly in my project folder. When i generate .jar file, xml file is stored in main folder in .jar.

```
private static final String PATH_TO_XML = "xmlOutput.xml";
```

This is working when I run project in Netbeans IDE. However, executing .jar file throws exception that file cannot be found. I tried some ways but i cannot find the way to specify path to file to be working in IDE and also as .jar file.

I read information about access as stream. However, my application executes XSLT transformation using XsltTemplate.xsl, xmlOutput.xml and htmlOutput.html so I need to use this file for transformation.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think about where the referenced files are stored in each context. If these are not packaged in the JAR like they are located in the IDE's project, then they won't be found. It might be best to configure the location in some configuration file and/or use an absolute path which is also available when running the JAR.